# Integrating some ios code into the PayPal Mobile Payments Library and am having some trouble with NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, paypal, stack-overflow, nsdecimalnumber

my first time on stackoverflow! I'm integrating some ios code into the PayPal Mobile Payments Library. As per the specification, I pass an object to one of the methods provided. The object contains a required property of type NSDecimalNumber*. I've used some sample code to set this property but this causes a stack overflow. The following is a line from my code:

```
details.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: @"10.00"];
```

and the following is an excerpt from the message log:

```
2012-12-11 15:30:50.189 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] Initialization In Progress
2012-12-11 15:30:53.956 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] NSScanner: nil string argument 
2012-12-11 15:30:53.965 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] NSScanner: nil string argument 
2012-12-11 15:30:53.977 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] NSScanner: nil string argument 
2012-12-11 15:30:53.982 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] 10 
2012-12-11 15:30:58.394 PayPalPOC3[595:f803] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'  
First throw call stack:
```

I've googled and have seen a number of overflow issues with the use of this type, but still can't glean anything obvious from my research. Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: I did a quick search and presuming you are getting the crash on the simulator - it may be that you location is set to a country that requires a comma for the cent separator unlike full stop that you are using. Try making your string $10,00 and see if that works.

Comment: Yes - crashing on the simulator. I've tried your suggestion but still no joy Jeff. The property is required (not optional)...the library is expecting this field.